# Matching HTML link with a specific title

Tags: php, html-parsing

How can I retrieve a URL from an HTML link with a specific begining title?

eg.:

```
<a href="http://urltoretrieve.ext/" title="specific title rest of all title">something</a>
<a href="http://otherurl.ext/" title="a generic title">somethingelse</a>
```

and use PHP to retrieve:

```
http://urltoretrieve.ext/
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: `my $url='http://urltoretrieve.ext/`

Comment: If this was tagged differently, say [tag:querypath], then `htmlqp($html)->find('a[title^="specific"]')->attr("href")` would be very easy.

Comment: @mario put it as an answer. I exchanged the regex tag for html-parsing since the OP doesnt mention regex in the question at all so I'd assume the OP just assumed regex is the right approach for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use https://gist.github.com/1358174 and this [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
//a[starts-with(@title, "specific title")]/@href
```

This query means:

```
//a                      find all a elements in the html
[                        that
starts-with(             
    @title               has a title attribute
    'specific-title'     starting with this value
)                        
]                        
/@href                   and return their href attribute
```

Example ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BxpB2M)):

```
$result = xpath_match_all(
    '//a[starts-with(@title, "specific title")]/@href', 
    $yourHtmlAsString
);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(38) "<href>http://urltoretrieve.ext/</href>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "http://urltoretrieve.ext/"
  }
}
```

The result is an array containing the serialized innerHTML and outerHTML of the found attribute nodes. If you dont understand what a node is, check [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

Also see [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Ha, no need. This already answers it nicely. Cool mini function!

Comment: Why the result retrieves me 2 arrays?

Comment: @davelab serialized innerHTML and outerHTML of the found attribute nodes because the function cannot know which one you want. If that is not what you want, you have to learn how to use DOM. The source code in the gist is a good starting point and there is also lots of examples at StackOverflow.

Comment: ok, for xPath solution: how can i exclude the outerHTML array?

Comment: @davelab it's an array, so just access the index for innerHTML if you are only interested in the innerHTML string/the value of the attribute, e.g. $result[1][0]

Comment: ok a solved with xPath thank you