# Exclude tag based on class and style in xpath

Tags: php, xml, regex, parsing, xpath

i have the following code to for xpath query...

```
<div class="buying">


<h1 class="parseasinTitle ">

<span id="btAsinTitle">Top Ten Tips for Growing Your Own Tomatoes (The Basic Art of Italian Cooking) <span style="text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 16px;">[Kindle Edition]</span></span>


</h1>
</div>
```

i just want to extract

> Top Ten Tips for Growing Your Own Tomatoes (The Basic Art of Italian Cooking)

so i am using `textContent` with the following xpath query

```
$xpath_books->query('//span[@id="btAsinTitle"]')
```

but the result is

> Top Ten Tips for Growing Your Own Tomatoes (The Basic Art of Italian Cooking) [Kindle Edition]

i think, i have to exclude `<span style="text-transform: capitalize; font-size: 16px;">` , to get my purpose, 
how can i do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//span[@id="btAsinTitle"]/text()
```

Comment: well, what i know is, text() function is used to extract the text from the node, but i am confusing here, Why it worked in my case? [kindle addition] is also a text? why so?

Comment: what i guess about the reason is, [kindle edition] is enclosed in another '<span>'  , so it was droped, and text arround the xpath selected span was extracted, Am I correct?

Comment: @NewBee, This query using `text()` function selects `span[@id="btAsinTitle"]` children text nodes. This span contains only 1 child node - `Top Ten Tips for Growing Your Own Tomatoes (The Basic Art of Italian Cooking)`. Text node `[Kindle Edition]` is child text node of other `span`.

Answer (score 4):

Your XPath does return the node with the id only, but because DOM is a tree of linked DOMNodes, the returned node will contain the child node. And when you access the returned span with `nodeValue` or `textContent`, PHP will return the combined DOMText nodes of all the children, including the child span holding "Kindle Edition".

```
      SPAN
     /    \
   TEXT   SPAN
            \
            TEXT
```

More on that at [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721)

If you want to fetch only the first text part, you have to fetch the nodeValue of the first childNode:

```
echo $result->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

An alternative to fetch that string with XPath directly would be

```
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//span[@id="btAsinTitle"]/text())');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php

If you want to return the whole DOMText node instead, use

```xml
//span[@id="btAsinTitle"]/text()
```

Comment: thanks @Gordon, what you answered was just I was asking to myself some moments ago..