# Xpath to Select nodes without its childrens

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

i've got a webpage that i would like to modify by code (adding link on specific words).

The HTML code:

```
<div class="section">
<h2>Notre histoire</h2>
<p style="text-align: justify;">SPECIFICS WORDS<strong>1998 : la création</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">pour objectif « de promouvoir, selon une démarche d’éducation active, auprès des jeunes et à travers eux, des projets d’expression collective et d’action de solidarité » (article 2).<br><br><strong>1999-2001 : les débuts SPECIFICS WORDS</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: justify;">SPECIFICS WORDS<a href="#">SPECIFICS WORDS</a></p>
</div>
```

So my aim is to preg_replace on SPECIFIC WORDS, but only those who are IN a P, but out from a A or a STRONG, or any either tags.

I can't use any class, or any id because i don't know the code before!
I tried preg_replace PHP function, but it didn't work, and was too long to execute.

So my question is:
How to select with XPATh a node without its A, STRONG, IMG chidrens ?

Comment: My first impression is that unless you're using XHTML and can guarantee that there are no special characters (like `&nbsp;`), you're going to have trouble getting to process via XPATH, as it would have to confirm to XML standards. I could be wrong though (has been known!)

Comment: In general the XPath expression to select a node that is in A but not in B is `A//node()[not(ancestor::B)]` If you want text nodes only, you need to replace `node()` with `text()`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot select nodes without their children. A node is a subpart of a tree, unless it is a leaf in which case it has not further children. To select the TextNode leaves containing the word "SPECIFIC" which are direct children of P elements, you do

```
//p/text()[contains(.,'SPECIFIC')]
```

This will exclude the text nodes inside other elements, e.g. in strong or a.

To replace them, you do

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//p/text()[contains(.,"SPECIFIC")]') as $textNode) {
    $textNode->nodeValue = "REPLACED";
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Also see [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721) and this [XPath Tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select all nodes in the Xml document that are direct children of a `<p>` element, without any other elements in between. This is possible as follows:

```
`//p/node()[not(self::*)]`
```

This expression selects

1. in all `<p>` elements
2. the immediate child nodes (without any intermediate levels)
3. unless they are elements.