# xpath handle double quotes with some other tags

Tags: xpath

I have this html sample

```
<html>
<body>
  ....
  <p id="book-1" class="abc">
    <b>
      <a href="xxx.html">book-1</a>
      <a href="xxx.html">section</a>
    </b>
       "I have a lot of "
        <i>different</i> 
       "text, and I want "
       <i>all</i>
       " text and we may or may not have italic surrounded text."
  </p>
  ....
```

the xpath I currently have is this:

```
@"/html[1]/body[1]/p[1]/text()"
```

this gives this result:

I have a lot of

but I want this result:

```
I have a lot of different text, and I want all text and we may or may not have italic surrounded text.
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with xpath by itself, [since you can't select a node without its children](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11154760/9448090). To do what you want to do, you'll have to use the host language. For example, BeautifulSoup in python.

Comment: If I really can't find a way, then I will have to extract from p and then use my process to do some regex. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In XPath 2 and higher you could use `string-join(/html[1]/body[1]/p[1]/b/following-sibling::node(), '')` I think. It is not quite clear which nodes you want but that would select all sibling nodes following the `b` child of the `p` and then concatenate their string values into one.

Comment: these text after b have no other nodes except sometimes there's italic node. so those text are under the p node.