# PHP DOMDocument hasAttribute is associated to which Elements?

Tags: php, xss, domdocument

I want to check all the tags under the body and check and remove if it has style attribute 
I have tried

```
$user_submitted_html = "This is Some Text";
$html = '<body>' . $user_submitted_html . '</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html_string);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach($elements as $element) {

   foreach($element->childNodes as $child) {

      if($child->hasAttribute('style')) {

          $child->removeAttribute('style')

      }      
   }  
 }
```

It works fine if `$user_submitted_html` is not only text, mean if it has some tags in it, but If it is only text then It gives the error

```
Call to undefined method DOMText::hasAttribute()
```

Then I get the nodeName in the foreach loop

```
echo "Node Name: " . $child->nodeName
```

It gives the

```
Node Name = #text
```

What kind of node name is this, I have echo'ed other nodes, it gives, div, span etc. that I am familiar with. 
I want to know that which are the elements that hasAttribute does not belong to them so I can put a condition before using the hasAttribute like this

```
if($child->nodeName=="#text") {
    continue; // skip to next iteration
}
if($child->hasAttribute('style')) {
.
.
.
```

OR any Other Solution???

One More Suggestion Required. What If I remove only the style attributes from `<div>,<span>,<p> and <a>`. Will it be safe from xss, if the rest of the tags can use style attribute.

Comment: This should help understanding the general concept of Nodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721. An easier approach than yours would be to use [XPath](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html) to query the Elements children of the body element having a style attribute directly, e.g. `/html/body/*[@style]`

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of checking the nodeName it would be better to check the class $child is an instance of.

```
if ( $child instanceof DOMElement )
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath for get only the elements with `style` attribute

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//[@style]');

foreach($elements as $e) {
    $e->removeAttribute('style')
}
```