# how fetch only part of html page

Tags: php, html

hi all my sample code is below :

```
  <?php 
  $html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>samplecode</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="warrper">
      <div class="box-title">This title is sample</div>
      <div class="box-maim">
        <div class="box-element-1">
           <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
              <li>sample 3</li>
              <li>sample 4</li>
              <li>sample 5</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box-element-1">
           <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
              <li>sample 3</li>
              <li>sample 4</li>
              <li>sample 5</li>
           </ul>   
        </div>
        <div class="box-element-1">
           <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
              <li>sample 3</li>
              <li>sample 4</li>
              <li>sample 5</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html> ';

   preg_match( '/<div class="box-maim">(.*?)<\/div>/si' , $html , $match );

   print_r($match);
  ?>
```

my aim after load html from url is , fetch just only tag part of selected class for example below code :

```
  <div class="box-element-1">
     <ul>
        <li>sample 1</li>
        <li>sample 2</li>
        <li>sample 3</li>
        <li>sample 4</li>
        <li>sample 5</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="box-element-1">
     <ul>
        <li>sample 1</li>
        <li>sample 2</li>
        <li>sample 3</li>
        <li>sample 4</li>
        <li>sample 5</li>
     </ul>   
  </div>
  <div class="box-element-1">
     <ul>
        <li>sample 1</li>
        <li>sample 2</li>
        <li>sample 3</li>
        <li>sample 4</li>
        <li>sample 5</li>
     </ul>
  </div>
```

but i dont know the correct methods of this action for that part .

Comment: You can do it with javascript or jQuery or you can use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) for PHP.

Comment: This regex will stop at first </div>

Comment: i have to fetch data server side , do not client side

Comment: @Console I am curious why do you suggest simplehtmldom if you have DomDocument and SimpleXML available by default on most installations of PHP this days. Is there a particular reason or just preference?

Comment: i don't know how use javascript or jquery server side ?!

Comment: thanks for help me , but i don't know how use DOMXPath

Comment: Then read the link above it shows how to use it and also have 3 links showing how to use it for specific things. There are very few and specific cases where you would like to use regex to parse HTML and believe me, yours isn't one of it.

Comment: can you show this sample how fetch with DOMXpath ?

Comment: A basic usage example can be found in [Grabbing the href attribute of an A element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/regular-expression-for-grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783) and a general conceptual overview can be found at [Noob question about DOMDocument in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/noob-question-about-domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721).

Comment: @rezataslimi_edu There's plenty of help already out there, including documentation.  Just search for it.

Comment: [How to use the DOM extension has been covered extensively on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+HTML+%5bPHP%5d&submit=search), so if you choose to use it, you can be sure most of the issues you run into can be solved by searching/browsing Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As all suggested to use DOM, try the below code:

```
<?php
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>samplecode</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="warrper">
      <div class="box-title">This title is sample</div>
      <div class="box-maim">
        <div class="box-element-1">
           <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
              <li>sample 3</li>
              <li>sample 4</li>
              <li>sample 5</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="box-element-1">
           <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
              <li>sample 3</li>
              <li>sample 4</li>
              <li>sample 5</li>
           </ul>   
        </div>
        <div class="box-element-1">
           <ul>
              <li>sample 1</li>
              <li>sample 2</li>
              <li>sample 3</li>
              <li>sample 4</li>
              <li>sample 5</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html> ';

$dom = new DOMDocument();    
$dom->loadHTML($html);    
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$div = $xpath->query('//div[@class="box-maim"]');    
$div = $div->item(0);    
echo $dom->saveXML($div);    
?>
```

It works perfectly :)

Comment: When will people stop using regex for dom manipulation...

Comment: thanks but tag body is not end always

Comment: @rezataslimi_edu more reason not to use a regex but a proper library that is meant for parsing HTML and is/was used/tested by millions of programmers.

Comment: oh then do preg_match_all for <div class="box-element-1">.

Comment: my english grammar is weak , i sorry for it .

Comment: hey EJTH and @rezataslimi_edu : i know preg_match is not recomened, but it comes handy for quick small tasks :P

Comment: @VishnuVishwa his quick and small task seems to have turned into a nightmare he can't solve and resulted in him posting it here for help and the fact he doesn't want to read anything else just means he wants to be spoonfed with the answer.

Comment: @rezataslimi_edu : edited answer please check.

Comment: @Prix : hey prix i am not pro to teach him stuffs, just an quick help...If he really not interested to learn stuffs , we cant force him to

Comment: @VishnuVishwa sure why not, its better to answer him and get 15 points then to point him on the right direction ;) so he can learn it.

Comment: @Prix : the thing is i myself dont know the right direction :P , as you guys said about DOM manipulation i am looking at them now :P

Comment: @VishnuVishwa glad this discussion at least made you read and check it out, there is a variety of libraries where DomDocument and SimpleXML are by default installed with most versions of PHP so they are ready to use.

Comment: my target is not class="box-element-1" ,my target is everything inner  class="box-maim"

Comment: Vishnu Vishwa thank for try answer me

Comment: @prix : I used DOM now :)

Comment: @VishnuVishwa and you have my down vote removed.

Answer (score -1):

If I am getting you properly, just do simply like that:

```
preg_match_all('/<div\s[^>]*class=\"box-element-([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*)<\/div>/siU', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: ha ha you could have seen comments in my answers before posting this :D

Comment: Please let me the sample output :-)

Comment: i mean preg_match is not recomended by any one here :P thats why -1 for you and -3 for me :D