# fetching value using DOMDocument in php

Tags: php

I have to fetch the value $1999.00 from the following code snippet...

```
<span class="mainprodpricez" itemprop="price">$1999.00
<span style="font-size:0.4em;display:block;"> including $100 cashback from Shopper</span>
<span style="font-size:0.4em;display:block;font-weight:bold;color:#cc0000;float:left;">You pay $2249.00 today. </span>
Details and claim form.</a></span>
```

To do this I have done the following coding:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $p) {

    if($p->getAttribute('class') == 'mainprodpricez') {

            $name = $p->nodeValue;

            }
}
```

This gives me the following result:

```
Â$1999.00 including Ã‚Â$100 cashback from Shopper You pay Â$2249.00 today. Details and claim form
```

Actually its fetching the whole nodeValue of the span class mainprodpricez...can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: which element or value are you gunning for anyway? the `$1999,00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodeValue` attribute gives you the *combined* text of all the child nodes. You want to get the text value of the first child text node only.

Change your code to

```
$name = $p->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

You can also do it with XPath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//span[@class="mainprodpricez"]/text()[1]';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate($query) as $price) {
    echo $price->nodeValue;
}
```

Also see my explanation in [DOMDocument in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721) for a general overview of the node concept.

Comment: @Gordon...thanks but again I got stuck in a almost similar issue...can you please help me there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436819/firstchild-in-domdocument-not-working