# firstChild in DOMDocument not working

Tags: php

Here is the code snippet from which I have to fetch the firstChild from the DIV named u-Row-6...

```
<div class="u-Row-6">
<div  class='article_details_price2'>
<strong >
855,90&nbsp;&euro; *
</strong>
<div class="PseudoPrice">
<em>EVP:  999,00&nbsp;&euro; *</em>
<span>
(14.32 % <span class="frontend_detail_data">gespart</span>)
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For this I have used the following code:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $p) {
    if ($p->getAttribute('class') == 'u-Row-6') {
        if ($first) {
            $name = $p->firstChild-nodeValue;
            $name = str_replace('€', '', $name);
            $name = str_replace(chr(194), " ", $name);
            $first = false;
        }
    }
}
```

But mysteriously this code is not working for me

Comment: Please use indentation when posting code samples, including HTML.

Comment: And what does "not working" mean? You'll get better and more answers if you are specific. What is happening, and what did you expect to happen.

Comment: where is that `$first` coming from and what is the expected output? You say the first child of the div with the class u-row-6. That would be the following div. Your code looks like you want to get the price in the strong element.

Comment: You are missing part of the arrow from `$p->firstChild-nodeValue;`. With what you have you will end up getting `firstChild` and trying to subtract a constant named `nodeValue`. This will throw a bunch of errors (undefined constant...etc).

Comment: @Gordon...yes I want to get the value in the strong element

Comment: @JonathanKuhn...yes I missed that -> but while putting the -> still am not getting the element in strong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a number of problems with your code:

- `$first` is not initialized to a `true` value, which will prevent the string replacement code from running even once
- The `$p->firstChild-nodeValue` lacks an `>` before `nodeValue`
- `$p->firstChild` will actually resolve to a text node (any text between `<div class="u-Row-6">` and `<div  class='article_details_price2'>`  - currently nothing), not the `strong` you are looking for and not `<div  class='article_details_price2'>` either, as one might have expected.

You may want to use an [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) query instead, to get all the `strong` tags within a `div` of class "u-Row-6", and then loop through the found tags:

```
$src = <<<EOS
<div class="u-Row-6">
<div  class='article_details_price2'>
<strong >
855,90&nbsp;&euro; *
</strong>
<div class="PseudoPrice">
<em>EVP:  999,00&nbsp;&euro; *</em>
<span>
(14.32 % <span class="frontend_detail_data">gespart</span>)
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
EOS;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($src);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$strongTags = $xpath->query('//div[@class="u-Row-6"]//strong');

foreach ($strongTags as $tag) {
    echo "The strong tag contents: " . $tag->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;

    // Replacement code goes here ...
}
```

Output:

```
The strong tag contents: 
855,90 € *
```

XPaths are actually quite handy. Read more about them [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).

Comment: @mhall...exactly the same am looking for...i am having lack of knowledge in xpath...thanks though to help me on this...thanks once again