# Regular expression - PHP Preg Match

Tags: php, regex

I am learning to use Regular expressions and would like to grab some data from a  table:

The file looks like this:

```
$subject = 
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Currently I am doing the following:

```
$pattern = "/<tr>.*?<td><\/td>.*?<td>(.*?)<\/td>.../s";
```

preg_match(
    $pattern,
    $subject,
    $result);

This will output an array:

```
$result = [
    0 => "tbody>...",
    1 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 3,
    4 => 4 ... n     
]
```

This seems inefficient so I am attempting to grab a repeated pattern like so:

```
$pattern = "/<td>([0-9]{1,2})<\/td>/s";
```

This however only grabs the first number: 1

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You mean you want the `g` flag?...

Comment: I am not sure, this is the first time I am working with regex.

Comment: The `s` modifier also has not effect on your current regex because you have no `.` in it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use preg_match_all instead of preg_match to perform the search on the entire var

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
if (preg_match_all( $pattern, $subject, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches);
}
```

Comment: Oh, that would likely work. Is it possible to add an AND operator to this?

Comment: what do you mean ? What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to firstly match a given pattern from a table: <tr><td>..</td></tr> then after that pull some static data: <span id='something'>data</span> then grab some further patterns... Or is it best to do this in seperate queries?

Comment: For more code clarity I would reccomend to do it in a separate query, it depends of the complexity of the regex

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to accomplish this using a parser:

```
$subject = '
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>';
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($subject);
$tds = $html->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach($tds as $td){
    echo $td->nodeValue . "\n";
    if(is_numeric($td->nodeValue)) {
        echo "it's a number \n"; 
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
it's a number 
2
it's a number 
3
it's a number 
4
it's a number 
5
it's a number 
6
it's a number
```

Comment: This looks interesting and may actually work for my needs. I just tried it out and I see it dies if there is an invalid tag in the HTML... is there a way around this?

Comment: It shouldn't die, it should just throw warnings, https://eval.in/489883 if you uncomment the two lines there you'll see the errors go away.

Comment: Are you able to recommend documentation for this? I would like to learn what else I can do.

Comment: The PHP site does, http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php. There's also a write up here on it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979836/domdocument-in-php/4983721#4983721

Answer (score 0):

To get all the values and not stopping after the first match you need to use the g flag.

In php this is implemented in the preg_match_all function.

Since the data will always be contained in a td you can do the following:

```
preg_match_all("/<td>(.*)<\/td>", $subject, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Where the $subject contains you html and you should see an array of all your table data.