# PHP XPath. How to return string with html tags?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domdocument, domxpath

```
<?php
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $html = '
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        Message <b>bold</b>, <s>strike</s>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="how">
            <a href="link" title="text">Link</a>, <b> BOLD </b>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    ';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;
    $dom->recover = true;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $messages = $xpath->query("//div");
    foreach($messages as $message)
    {
        echo $message->nodeValue;
    }
```

This code returns "Message bold, strike Link, BOLD " without html tags...

I want to output the following code:

```
Message <b>bold</b>, <s>strike</s>

<span class="how">
     <a href="link" title="text">Link</a>, <b> BOLD </b>
</span>
```

Can you help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Answer (score 1):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
foreach($messages as $message)
{
    echo $dom->saveHTML($message); 
}
```

Use `saveHTML()`

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't see this function anywhere else in similar questions, and it's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it using [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) really quickly (if it's okay for you to switch from DOMDocument and DOMXPath, probably you will go with my solution):

```
$html = '
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        Message <b>bold</b>, <s>strike</s>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="how">
            <a href="link" title="text">Link</a>, <b> BOLD </b>
        </span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
    ';
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
    $arr = $xml->xpath('//div/*');
    foreach ($arr as $x) {
      echo $x->asXML();
    }
```