# PHP: how to get the correct closing tag of an HTML element

Tags: php, regex, xpath, domdocument

Assuming that I have an HTML page as follows:

```
<!-- This is the opening tag -->
<div class="content_text">
  <div>Title</div>
  <div>Author Name</div>
  <div>Some complicated HTML elements correctly validated</div>
  <b>Some more text</b>
  <img ... />
  <div> more and more text </div>
</div><!-- This is the correct closing tag -->
```

How do I get the content between the opening of the div with `class="content_text"` and its correct closing tag?

I tried regular expressions, but I couldn't find any easy or even hard way to do it.

I tried [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), but I still couldn't get the content. Instead I got the text inside the outer div.

Comment: Not sure of your specific application.. but any chance of using jQuery? Its [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method seems like it would be useful.

Comment: No, it's a server-side script

Comment: @showdev jQuery is clientside, and since the OP tagged this as PHP, I don't think he'll need it.

Comment: @Shehabix could you provide a simplified sample and the code you tried ?

Comment: Well, I just found a solution for it using DOMDocument, I'll post it in case anyone else needed a similar thing..

Comment: Not the right regex, but it works for this example `preg_match_all('/<div class="content_text">(\s*<.*?>.*?<\/div>\s*|\s*<.*? \/>\s*)<\/div>/s', $html, $m);`, but to make it clear just use DOM !

Comment: No Regex won't work here as the content isn't always the same, sometimes it has many many nested tags of the same type (div).

Comment: @Shehabix: You can match same-tags inside if they are properly paired, there is recursion in PCRE. http://php.net/regexp.reference.recursive

Comment: @hakre could you give me an example code or something, I never succeeded in matching it using recursion.

Comment: @Shehabix: Sure, I found this blog-post good for an introduction in this specific feature of PCRE: [Parse with regular expressions (Nov 2007; by Kore Nordmann)](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/parse_with_regexp.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    $scrape_address = "http://www.al-madina.com/node/444862";
    $ch = curl_init($scrape_address);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, '1'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    // I couldn't get an element by Attribute so I just replaced class to id
    $data = str_replace('class="content_text"','id="my_unique_id"',$data);

    $domd = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $domd->loadHTML($data);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $div = $domd->getElementById("my_unique_id");

    if ($div) {
      $dom2 = new DOMDocument();
      $dom2->appendChild($dom2->importNode($div, true));
      echo $dom2->saveHTML();
    } else {
      echo "Nothing found";
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) to parse HTML like `DOMDocument` would for XML.

> *Note:* [PHP has support for DOMDocument directly as well](http://php.net/DOMDocument).

Comment: That parser has been written for PHP 4, PHP 5 ships with its own HTML parser called *DOMDocument* the method to load HTML is called *loadHTML*.

Comment: @hakre, This parser [*requires*](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net) PHP5 to work. And it explicitly says it was written for PHP5.

Comment: Yes it does, but it has been written for PHP 4. Since PHP 5 the need was gone. Sure the lib was ported to PHP 5 but I would say it has overlived its time because the pre-condition for what it has been created (PHP w/o HTML parser) is not the situation any longer (PHP is with HTML parser).

Comment: @hakre, so you have downvoted this answer because I suggested a library that *you* consider to have *overlived its time* but totally works and fits in the requirements of this question?

Comment: No because the answer is (more) wrong. The suggested library does not follow the DOM Specification for HTML documents nor follows it the rules of CSS selectors (not even for the subset it says it supports), nor does it properly parse HTML.

Comment: @hakre, Can you provide an example of how wrong this library is in *any* of the things you have listed, and how `DOMDocument` does a better job on that? I'm really curious.

Comment: Just take a look at the issue tracker of simple html dom. Many examples are documented. DOMDocument on the other hand runs on a library used by millions in many different software products (libxml) and is pretty well maintained. It is also much faster and memory friendly. On the other hand I'm also curious why users are still preferring simple HTML dom. I see it on SO from time to time that it's suggested and I often really wonder. Maybe you can say why from your perspective?

Comment: @hakre, "Just take a look at the issue tracker of simple html dom", seems a vague reference to me. But anyway I now understand and accept your point of view. And no, I wouldn't know why they use it. They might need to parse some HTML content from a page they do not have control over. Don't really know.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest PHP's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) - unless the content will be always structured exactly the same way, regular expressions won't do, and even then it's not going to be pretty.

Also, here is a [question about a similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177987/php-xpath-how-to-return-string-with-html-tags) that was solved by using SimpleXML, maybe that can help.

Comment: "The DOM extension allows you to operate on XML documents". It's for XML.

Comment: DOMDocument works with HTML, too, e.g., http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: I found the solution to my situation and posted it already few minutes ago, using DOMDocument

Answer (score 0):

*You already seem to be able to successfully run XPath queries, so I'm omitting PHP code and get straight to the XPath part.*

Not sure what you mean by "content", so I'm offering some alternatives:

You want all text nodes inside the `<div/>`:

```
//div[@class="content_text"]//text()
```

You want all XML including the elements:

```
//div[@class="content_text"]
```

Both will return a set of results, be sure to loop over it.