# Getting contents of a div with PHP's DOM

Tags: php, domdocument

I've looked through the other Stackoverflow questions on this topic and none of the solutions provided there seem to work for me.

I have an html page (scraped with `file_get_contents()`) and in that html is a div with an id of "main" - I need to get the contents of that div with PHP's DOMDocument, or something similiar. For this situation I can't use the SimpleHTMLDom parser, which complicates things a bit.

Comment: When you say *I need to get the contents of that div* do you mean a the HTML?

Comment: [DOMElement getElementById ( string $elementId )](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DOMDocument + XPath variation:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHtml($temp);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

$html = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@id="main"]/*') as $node)
{
    $html .= $xml->saveXML($node);
}
```

---

If you're looking for [`innerHTML()` (PHP DOMDocument Reference Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) - instead of `innerXML()` as in this answer - the xpath related variant is given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17264261/367456).

Here the adoption with the changes underlined:

```
$html = '';
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@id="main"]/node()') as $node)
                                          ######
{
    $html .= $xml->saveHTML($node);
                       ####
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$main = $dom->getElementById('main');
```

To get the serialised HTML...

```
html = '';
foreach($main->childNodes as $node) {
    $html .= $dom->saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
}
```

Use [`saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) if your PHP version supports it.