# XPath savehtml remove parent element

Tags: php, xpath, parent

I want to get the HTML inside the parent element. For example, I have this structure:

```
<div>
<div>text<b>more text</b>and <i>some more</i></div>
</div>
```

and I want to get `text<b>more text</b>and <i>some more</i>` as a result.

Here's my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadhtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$text = $xpath->query("//div/div");
$html = $dom->saveHTML($text->item(0));
```

And the result is

```
<div>text<b>more text</b>and <i>some more</i></div>
```

I thought of using preg_replace but it's not a good idea. How can I remove the parent element using XPath?

Comment: You are looking for something known as *innerHTML* which was a non-standard thing in early versions of the DOM (in browsers). As you might imagine you're not the first one who asks for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might need

```
$html = '';
foreach ($text->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
  $html .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}
```

That's pseudo code iterating over the child nodes of the `div` element node, I hope I got the PHP syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking onto your problem to *remove* the parent (which is confronting yourself with the problematic output and then thinking you need to remove something), just turn it 180°  around and consider to not add it in the first place. That is saving the HTML of all child-nodes of that div.

First the xpath expression for all child-nodes of `//div/div`:

```
//div/div/node()
```

That means in xpath to query *any* node-type, so not only element-nodes for example but also the text-nodes which you need here.

So you now want to use `$dom->saveHTML()` on all these nodes. This can be done by mapping that function call onto all those items:

```
$inner = $xpath->query("//div/div/node()");
$html  = implode('', array_map([$dom, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($inner)));
```

This will make `$html` the following:

```
text<b>more text</b>and <i>some more</i>
```

Instead of mapping you can also use the bit more verbose code that is probably more easy to read:

```
$inner = $xpath->query("//div/div/node()");

$html = '';
foreach($inner as $node) {
    $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Compared with the previous answer you can see it's similar but a bit more simplified because it uses the xpath expression to query the elements to save *directly*.