# I am creating tags in html file but special characters are converted into their codes

Tags: php, xml

```
php part

<?php
    $f = fopen( "temp.xml","r" );
    $str = "";
    while( $line = fgets($f) ){
        if( !($line[1]=='?' || $line[1]=='b' || $line[2]=='b') ){
            $str.= $line."<br>";
        }
    }
    fclose( $f );

    $xdoc = new DomDocument;
    $xdoc->Load('text.xml');
    $body = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('textBody')->item(0);

    $txtNode = $xdoc ->createTextNode ( $str );
    $body -> appendChild($txtNode);

    $test = $xdoc->save("text.xml");
?>

xml file updated.

<textBody>      
    &lt;br&gt;          
    &lt;br&gt; &amp;#13;
    &lt;br&gt;&lt;font&gt;Heading Here...&lt;/font&gt;&amp;#13;
    &lt;br&gt;&lt;font&gt;Text Here...&lt;/font&gt;&amp;#13;
    &lt;br&gt;
</textBody>



I want to create child in xml file but the special characters are converted into their codes as shown above.
I want the output as

<br><br>
<br><font>Heading Here </font>
<br><font>Text Here</font>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A textNode contains only character-data.

If you like to create and insert a fragment containing multiple element-nodes use [DOMDocument::createDocumentFragment](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php)

```
$xdoc = new DomDocument;
$xdoc->Load('text.xml');
$body = $xdoc->getElementsByTagName('textBody')->item(0);

$fragment = $xdoc ->createDocumentFragment ();
$fragment->appendXML( $str );
$body -> appendChild($fragment);
```

**Please note:** `appendXML()` is not a part of the DOM, it's a PHP-implementation.

If you like to do it a "clean" DOM-way, create a new document, load the string using loadXML() and import the result into the other document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$txtNode = $xdoc ->createTextNode ( $str );
```

You've asked for some text, and what you've got is text. `&lt;` means the literal left-angle-bracket character.

If you want to insert raw markup into a document, like setting `innerHTML` in a browser, you'd have to create a new document, load the markup into it, and import the resulting DOM nodes into your target document. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) for how to do that.

However:

```
<textBody>
    <br><br>
    ...
</textBody>
```

That's not well-formed XML so can't be included as markup in an XML document. If you are storing arbitrary HTML inside an XML file, you should carry on doing it as text content, because HTML markup is not the same as XML markup (unless you're using XHTML).