# Getting the Inner HTML of a DomElement in PHP

Tags: php, dom

What's the simplest way to get the innerHTML (tags and all) of a DOMElement using PHP's DOM functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$html = '';
foreach($parentElement->childNodes as $node) {
   $html .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lVphPX).

Comment: This doesn't work if the childNodes have childNodes though

Comment: @babonk That's not true. Look at the bottom of the CodePad.

Comment: Weird, I got an error locally when I used it.. might be a version thing

Comment: @babonk `saveHTML()` with a node is only supported >= 5.3.6. You may need to use `saveXML()` if using a prior version.

Answer (score 3):

#### Inner HTML

Try approach suggested by [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193507/55075):

> `$html = implode(array_map([$node->ownerDocument,"saveHTML"], iterator_to_array($node->childNodes)));`

#### Outer HTML

Try:

```
$html = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
```

or in PHP lower than 5.3.6:

```
$html = $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($node);
```