# How to fetch html string of XPath results?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

Considering this code:

```
<div class="a">foo</div>
<div class="a"><div id="1">bar</div></div>
```

If I want to fetch all the values of divs with class **a**, I'll do the following query:

```
$q = $xpath->query('//div[@class="a"]');
```

However, I'll get this result:

```
foo
bar
```

But I want to get the actual value including the children tags. So it'll look like that:

```
foo
<div id="1">bar</div>
```

How can I accomplish that with XPath and DOMDocument only?

---

Solved by the function provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument).

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156054/getting-the-inner-html-of-a-domelement-in-php) [countless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/domdocument-savehtml-without-html-wrapper) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615389/innerhtml-in-xpath) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
$xml = '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\' ?>
    <root>
    <div class="a">foo</div>
    <div class="a"><div id="1">bar</div></div>
    </root>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);            
var_dump($xml->xpath('//div[@class="a"]'));
```

But in this case you will have to iterate objects.

Output:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(1) "a"
    }
    [0]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["class"]=>
      string(1) "a"
    }
    ["div"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
 }

Comment: But it also retrieves only bar in my case.

Comment: Sorry, you were right. However, it has no the `id` attribute (or am I missing something?). I mean, the `<div id="1">`. And the structure is pretty complex. Even if it was showing me the `id` attribute, I'd still have to transform all that stuff to a plain text.

Answer (score 0):

PHP DOM has an undocumented ['.nodeValue'](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php#92571) attribute which acts exactly like `.innerHTML` in a browser. Once you've used XPath to get the node you want, just do `$node->nodeValue` to get the innerhtml.

Comment: That's **exactly** what I do. But nodeValue does not interpret the children as actual value of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML('<div>Your HTML here.</div>');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('//div[@class="a"]')->item(0);
$html = $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node); // Get HTML of DOMElement.
```