# Getting image links between anchor tag via php dom parser

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to read all links with in a given url.

here is code I am using :

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
$urls = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($urls as $url) {
        echo $url->innertext ." => ".$url->getAttribute('href');
```

Script giving all links of given url.

But problem here is I am not able to get image links (image inside anchor tag)

First I tried with

> $url->nodeValue

But it was giving anchor text having text values only.

I want to read both images and text links.
I want output in below formmat.

Input :

```
<a href="link1.php">first link</a>
<a href="link2.php"> <img src="imageone.jpg"></a>
```

Current Output:

```
first link => link1.php
=>link2.php with warning (Undefined property: DOMElement::$innertext )
```

Required Output :

```
first link => link1.php
<img src="imageone.jpg">=>link2.php
```

Comment: What's the output you're getting? What output do you want?

Comment: getting only href values. and for text/image b/w anchor tag giving warning "Undefined property: DOMElement::$innertext in /home/url/public_html/crawl2.php"

Comment: @Alfred that doesnt help to clarify your question. Please provide a sample markup and some output you want to fetch from it. As for innerText: there is no such property in a DOMNode or DOMElement.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks. Now updated with current and required output. Please see updated question

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerText` doesn't exist in PHP; it's a non-standard, Javascript extension to the DOM.

I *think* what you want is effectively an `innerHTML` property.  There isn't a native way of achieving this.  You can use the `saveXML` or, from PHP 5.3.6, `saveHTML` methods to export the HTML of each of the child nodes:

```
function innerHTML($node) {
    $ret = '';
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $node) {
        $ret .= $node->ownerDocument->saveHTML($node);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

<sub>Note that you'll need to use `saveXML` before PHP 5.3.6</sub>

You could then call it as so:

```
echo innerHTML($url) ." => ".$url->getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: Can you please update your answer according to my code.Actully I am not getting exactly.

Comment: giving error "DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given".

Comment: @Alfred See the note in my answer. You're clearly using an older version of PHP. Changing `saveHTML` to `saveXML` should make it work OK.