# How to use an object as a parameter for PHP's createElement

Tags: php, xml, dom

I'm using a variable to create an element. But I'm getting this error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::createElement() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

```
// load up your XML
$xml = new DOMDocument;

$xml->load('test.xml');    

$parent_node = $xml->createElement('parent');

foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('product') as $product ) 
{
 $append = array();

foreach($product->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name ) {
// Stick $name onto the array
$append[] = $name;
}

foreach ($append as $a)  {

$parent_node->appendChild($xml->createElement($a, 'anothervalue'));

 $product->appendChild($parent_node);

}


$product->removeChild($xml->getElementsByTagName('details')->item(0));
//$product->appendChild($element);
}

// final result:

$result = $xml->saveXML();
```

Original XML structure:

```
<products>
 <product>
 <name>text</name>
 <name>text</name>
 <name>text</name>
 </product>
 </products>
```

I'm trying to create a new element whose value is the text of itself. I know what it has to look like. Why can't I use an object to create an element?

The result I'm trying to obtain will look like this:

```
 <products>
 <product>
 <text>text</text>
 <text>text</text>
 <text>text</text>
 </product>
 </products>
```

Comment: Because `createElement` expects a string and not an object. Do you have any particular question?

Comment: Is it possible to use the inner text of an existing element to create a new element?

Comment: like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument? or just the "text" (without possible child elements), e.g. what should the result be when there `<name>text<foo>bar</foo></name>`? or will it always be just "text"?

Comment: without possible child elements. So I would use create a new element <bar></bar> for each of the <foo></foo> elements

Comment: so it should be `<text>text<bar>bar</bar></text>` then?

Comment: Yes That's what I am trying to do. I'm using the values between <foo>Bar</bar> as a field in a database to ultimately use mysql load xml infile and have the rows be identified by Bar. But I need to make tags for each field. It might sound confusing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5881/discussion-between-rpm-and-gordon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass an object, you must use the `textContent` or `nodeValue` properties:

```
$element = $xml->createElement(trim($a->textContent), 'anothervalue');
```

You may also want to strip it from illegal characters first:

```
$nodeName = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_-]/i', '', $a->textContent);
$element = $xml->createElement($nodeName, 'anothervalue');
```

Answer (score 1):

declare the array befor the foreach loop otherwise it will become empty every time when one loop will complete

```
    $append = array();
    foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('product') as $product ) 
    {
         foreach($product->getElementsByTagName('name') as $name ) {
             // Stick $name onto the array
             $append[] = $name;
          }

         foreach ($append as $a)  {
              $parent_node->appendChild($xml->createElement($a, 'anothervalue'));
              $product->appendChild($parent_node);
          }

         $product->removeChild($xml->getElementsByTagName('details')->item(0));
         //$product->appendChild($element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent_node->appendChild($xml->createElement($a->nodeValue, 'anothervalue'));
```

This get element value, if you wanna get the element name .. use '`$a->nodeName`'

Answer (score 0):

Just change this one line

$append[] = $name;

to 
$append[] = $name->tagName;

It should work then

Comment: no, it wont. OP is looking for "text" not "name", e.g. nodevalue