# php preg_match_all() how to get correct values in match-array

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

The following situation:

```
$text = "This is some <span class='classname'>example</span> text i'm writing to
demonstrate the <span class='classname otherclass'>problem</span> of this.<br />";

preg_match_all("|<[^>/]*(classname)(.+)>(.*)</[^>]+>|U", $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

I need an array ($matches) where in one field is "**`<span class='classname'>example</span>`**" and in another "**example**".
But what i get here is one field with "`<span class='classname'>example</span>`" and one with "classname".

It also should contain the values for the other matches, of course.

how can i get the right values?

Comment: Best advice: forget regexes exist, and switch to using DOM. It'll take you far less time to come up with a nice simple XPath query and a few dom node-extraction calls than it will to get the equivalent regex working - plus you won't beat your brain into a pulp doing so.

Comment: Die Cthulu, die!! Go back from whence you came... how long... noooo darkness reigns supreme [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) **JUST PARSE THE HTML**

Comment: [The pony, he comes...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1338999)

Comment: I have to agree, there are better ways for parsing HTML (as linked above).  However, have you tried dumping your $matches variable? A copy paste of your code and a var_dump, provided me with $matches[3] as an array containing the values you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you Chris: That's the right answer! √

Comment: Just a slight remark: Why would anyone use pipes as regex delimiters?? that's like amputating a limb, IMHO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off with a DOM parser, however this question is more to do with how capturing works in Regexes in general.

The reason you are getting `classname` as a match is because you are capturing it by putting `()` around it. They are completely unnecessary so you can just remove them. Similarly, you don't need them around `.+` since you don't want to capture that.

If you had some group that you had to enclose in `()` as grouping rather than capturing, start the group with `?:` and it won't be captured.

Answer (score 0):

The safe/easy way:

```
$text = 'blah blah blah';

$dom = new DOM();
$dom->loadHTML($text);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xp->query("//span[@class='classname']");
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $innertext = $node->nodeValue;
    $html =  // see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument
}
```