# Remove <html> and <head> tags at DOMDocument::saveXML

Tags: php, dom

I have a part of html that is incompletely structured.
Example:

```
<div id='notrequired'>
    <div>
        <h3>Some examples :-)</h3>
        STL is a library, not a framework.
    </div> 
    </p>
    </a>
    <a target='_blank' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29'>Read more</a>;
</div>
<a target='_blank' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29'>Read more</a>";
```

As you can notice here I have unexpected `</p>` and `</a>` tags.

I tried a snippet of code to remove the `<div id='notrequired'>` and it works, but unable to handle it precisely.

Here's the snippet code:

```
function DOMRemove(DOMNode $from) {
            $from->parentNode->removeChild($from);
        }

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($text); //$text contains the above mentioned HTML

        $selection = $dom->getElementById('notrequired');
        if($selection == NULL){
            $text = $dom->saveXML();
        }else{
            $refine = DOMRemove($selection);
            $text = $dom->saveXML($refine);
        }
```

The problem is `$dom->saveXML` saves as HTML content:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
        <html>

<body>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29">Read more</a>

    </body>    
    </html>
```

All I only need is:

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29'>Read more</a>
```

And not the `<HTML>` and `<BODY>` tags.

What am I missing? Any other way of doing it better?

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument) - get the `innerHTML` of the `<body>` element. Job done.

Comment: the function you gave shouldn't return anything...

Comment: @hakre, Thanks for point it out. Will check the solution.

Comment: @AlexLunix, the sample I posted is working fine. What have I missed that you pointed it should return nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.. I guess I figured out a solution. Approach may not be right, but, it does the job!

As [Hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811604/remove-html-and-head-tags-at-domdocumentsavexml#comment17327292_12811604) pointed out that it's the exact duplicate as [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument), It is not exact duplicate but it gave me a hint to use the idea. Thanks for suggestion.

It helped me frame a solution below:

```
function DOMRemove(DOMNode $from) {
    $from->parentNode->removeChild($from);
}

function DOMinnerHTML($element) 
{ echo "Ashwin";
    $innerHTML = ""; 
    $children = $element->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
        $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveHTML()); 
    }
    return $innerHTML; 
}

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
@$dom->loadHTML($test);

$a = $dom->getElementById('step');

$b = DOMRemove($a);
$c = $dom->saveXML($b);

$domTable = $dom->getElementsByTagName("body"); 

foreach ($domTable as $tables) 
{ 
    $x = DOMinnerHTML($tables); 
    echo $x; 
}
```

If the input is:

```
<div id='step'>
    <div >
        <h3>Some examples :-(</h3>
        Blah blah blah...
    </div> </p>
    </a>
    <a target='_blank' href='#'>Read more</a>;
</div>
<div id='step2'>
    <div>
        <h3>Some examples :-) :-D</h3>
        Blah2 blah2 blah2...
    </div> </p> </a>
</div>
<a target='_blank' href='#'>Read more</a>
<a target='_blank' href='#'>Read more</a>
<a target='_blank' href='#'>Read more</a>
```

The output, as expected, is:

```
<div id="step2">
    <div>
        <h3>Some examples :-) :-D</h3>
        Blah2 blah2 blah2...
    </div> 
</div>
<a target="_blank" href="#">Read more</a>
<a target="_blank" href="#">Read more</a>
<a target="_blank" href="#">Read more</a>
```

The solution works but may not optimal. **Any thoughts?**