# echo innerHTML, without outer node tags

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm using the `DOMDocument` class to parse a fairly unpredictable string of markup. It's not all that well formed and I need some data from it. Regex's are right out, of course.
So far, I've got this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$contents = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
echo $dom->saveXML($contents);
```

Now this gives me:

```
<body>
    <p>What I'm really after</p>
    <ul><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li></ul>
    <h6>And so on</h6>
</body>
```

What really annoys me are those `<body>` tags. I want them gone. After grazing the web, I've stumbled across the weirdest workarounds. Some more hacky than others, so in the end, I settled for:

```
echo substr($dom->saveXML($contents), 6, -7);
```

Still feels hacky to me, but it's the best I could find. Is there a more reliable way of getting the innerHTML of the DOM, starting from a given node, without the corresponding tags actually showing up?

I've seen suggestions using regex's (a no-no IMHO), or even looping through all the children, echoing those that have childNodes of their own, and stringing together those that don't:

```
if ($contents->hasChildNodes())
{
    $children = $contents->getElementsByTagName('*');
    foreach($children as $child)
    {
        if ($child->hasChildNodes() || $child->nodeName === 'br')
        {//or isset($standaloneNodes[$child->nodeName])
            echo $dom->saveXML($child);
            continue;
        }

        echo '<'.$child->nodeName.'>'.$child->nodeValue.'</'.$child->nodeName.'>';
    }
}
```

But that, to me, seems even more absurd...

Comment: is the `<body>` tag always present? Do you want to remove ALL the tags?

Comment: @Harsh: The `<body>` tag is being added by `DOMDocument` (along with a doctype and `<head>` tag. All I want to do is parse the HTML, so I can get at some bits of data I need, and return a normalized version of the markup

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument

Comment: @Harsh: I already have, compared to `substr($dom->saveXML($contents), 6, -7);`, the answer there is _way_ too inefficient.

Comment: if you are gunning for speed, Kolink's solution isn't bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exporting HTML, you must have a single root element. In most cases, the most useful one is the `body`. Since you're loading in an HTML fragment, you know for certain that it won't have any attributes, therefore the `substr(...,6,-7)` is perfectly predictable and fine.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It still feels a bit hacky... anyway: I'm done working for the day, but I'll accept your answer once I get home.

Comment: yea, it is hacky, but does the job well. Although I'd fear using this due to its opaque purpose. :P

Comment: @Harsh: That's why all programming languages I've ever used allow for comments...

Comment: @Harsh: That, and `preg_replace('/^[^>]+>(.+)<[^>]+>$/',$1',$dom->saveXML($contents));`, which is, in theory, a more reliable way to strip the outer tags in 1 line, calls Cthulu