# Php strip template

Tags: php, html

I have some html templates witch have this format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <title>myTitle</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   
</head> 
<body bgcolor="#b23bba" style="background-color: #b23bba; margin: 0;"> 
    <table>
        <tr><td><img src="https://www.myurlname.com/anotherimg.jpg" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>needed content</td></tr>
    </table>
    <img src="https://www.myurlname.com/e68f2e83c811d6bdb32876041a1cfa78.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</body>
</html>
```

What is need to do is to strip this template, take just a part of it and insert it into another template witch already have html general html tags like html,head or body. What I need exactly is to keep only what I have between the body tags but without the image witch has 1px height and width.

For this particular case I have to keep only the table. I have to mention that I store all this content into a php variable. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem?  if so, what code have you produced and how did it go?

Comment: if you're looking to extract part of an html document/fragment, then you want [DOM](http://php.net/dom).

Comment: I was thinking about a solution for this but i did not find any until now. Usually i use str_replace("</body></html>", "", $myphpvar); to remove some of the code, but i still can't find a solution to remove complex code like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, considering you have a full, and valid DOM, you can just parse it, query the `<body>` node, and store that. It only takes a couple of lines of code, using [the `DOMDocument` class](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$contents = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$bodyContents = $dom->saveXML($contents);
```

This will yield:

```
<body><!-- your markup here --></body>
```

To get rid of the body tags, a simple `substr` call will do:

```
$clean = substr($bodyContents, 6, -7);
```

And that's it! [Here's a more full example BTW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840683/echo-innerhtml-without-outer-node-tags).

Of course, if your `<body>` tags may contain attributes, you'll have to remove those, first. Generally, something like this should work:

```
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
if ($body->hasAttributes())
{
    foreach($body->attributes as $attr)
    {
        $body->removeAttributeNode($attr);
    }
}
```

It's all documented rather well [here, on the official PHP pages](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

As it turns out, `foreach` doesn't quite cut it, so here's the fixed code in full:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
//avoid unwanted HTML entities (like &#13;) from popping up:
$str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $str);
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$contents = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
while($contents->hasAttributes())
{//as long as hasAttributes returns true, remove the first of the list
    $contents->removeAttributeNode($contents->attributes->item(0));
}
//remove last image:
$imgs = $contents->getElementsByTagName('img');//get all images
if ($imgs && $imgs->length)
{//if there are img tags:
    $contents->removeChild($imgs->item($imgs->length -1));//length -1 is last element
}
$bodyContents = $dom->saveXML($contents);
$clean = trim(substr($bodyContents, 6, -7));//remove <body> tags
```

And [Here's the proof that it works](http://codepad.org/eJOlENMi)
Now, a version without those annoying HTML entities [of the same codepad](http://codepad.org/NhVXHevk)

And now, finally, a codepad [that removes the last img tag from the DOM, too](http://codepad.org/fkeJ3Nfb)

Comment: Thank you for your answere, i am testing it right now and come back after i have a conclusion.

Comment: By the way, you wrote there $bodyContents = $dom->saveXML($bodyContents); but you it should be $bodyContents = $dom->saveXML($contents); right ?

Comment: And one more thing, as i said it in the question, i also want to remove the image that is under the table, because that is a visitor counter from another template witch is not needed here.

Comment: In your output also appeares this char: &#13; do you know what it is or how to remove it ?

Comment: To remove a node, just query the DOM for that node, and remove it (it's all in the docs): `$dom->removeChild($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0));`. As for that entity (`&#13;`) that's some sort of line-feed (perhaps carriage return, perhaps just a new line. you could remove that by using `str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $html_string);` before parsing the DOM. PS: thant you comments are actively discouraged. The proper way of saying thanks is to vote an answer up (and/or accept it)

Comment: This line is helpfull $dom->removeChild($dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0));, but it does not work in case i have another image put in a row of a table. It crashes. Any other solution?

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora: I don't know what your markup looks like, but you'll have to use `$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img'); if ($imgs){}` to check if there _are_ images in the DOM, then `foreach` that list, and  remove the img node you want to remove...

Comment: I've updated the code. All i need is to remove the image witch is right before the /body tag and it has width and height set to 1px.

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora: please, do try a thing or two yourself, but from what I gather: `$lastImg = end($imgs);` should get the last image in the DOM

Comment: This project is a very big project and i work on all other parts alone, this thing is something that i am not good at, and the documentation is very big to read it all now and understand it also. So, in this case, either you have a solution for this, write it in your answere, because your answere its incomplete, it resolves just a part of my question, or either don't say anything. If your answere is like this : try to do something by your self, that is not helpfull. I already did in fact, and because my problem is not resolved yet i am still writing here.

Comment: So thanks for the answeres but i am waiting for a complete and good answere. If you want to complete your answere i will mark you as a good answere if not, i am waiting for another one, thanks.

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora: Your initial question was _"How do I extract the body from this markup"_, I've answered that question. You say you've tried a lot of things, yet you don't _show_ your efforts, even though [it is explicitly asked of you to do so](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I've tried to be reasonable, responding to your comments, trying to suggest possible solutions, for cases of which I have _no_ examples. I'm working blind here. So if you want to remove a specific node, based on its place in the DOM + certain attributes, that's a different question, post it separatly

Comment: No, you are wrong. My initial question was: "What I need exactly is to keep only what I have between the body tags but without the image witch has 1px height and width." You can check that to see that this appeared from the start and i did not edit that. So your answere is uncomplete.

Comment: I've mentioned that i need to keep everything inside body except that image. So, again, i appreciate that you helped me until now, but your answere was not complete.

Comment: @CrisanRalucaTeodora: Well, I've added the couple of lines of code that'll remove the last img tag from the markup, too. I've added another codepad link to the end of my answer.