# loadHTML/saveHTML DOM problems

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

After running the following code, I get "No Match":

```
$testcontent = '<div><p>Reader&rsquo;s Digest & More!</p></div>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($testcontent);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$testcon = $xpath->query('*');

echo $testcontent . '<br />';

foreach ($testcon->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {
    $savehtml = $dom->saveHTML($child);
}

echo $savehtml . '<br />';

if ($testcontent == $savehtml) {
    echo "Match";
}
else {
    echo "No Match";
}
```

Can anyone tell me why either the `loadHTML` function or the `saveHTML` function seems to change the HTML I'm passing in. I would expect this code to echo "Match", but for some reason, even though the echoed text on the page looks the same for both, the second version is somewhat altered in that the `&` character has been changed to `&amp`. Is there anyway to avoid this automatic conversion?

This is the source of the output of the page:

```
<div><p>Reader&rsquo;s Digest & More!</p></div>
<div><p>Reader’s Digest &amp; More!</p></div>
No Match
```

You'll see above how the HTML gets altered somewhat.

Comment: I would work with the LIBXML constants and the html encode/decode functions to get the text into a standard format before you hand it off to DOMDocument (which uses LIBXML).

Comment: `DOMDocument` parses the given string, and turns it into a full DOM tree, complete with `<html><head><body>` tags. The original string does _not_ have these tags, and therefore the two strings won't match. Perhaps [take a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840683/echo-innerhtml-without-outer-node-tags) on how to get the same DOM fragment back

Comment: Why don't you just view the page source?

Comment: Also & should be &amp;

Comment: I added the page source to my question above. You will see the output of the two echo statements.

Answer (score 0):

To see the HTML, use `DOMDocument::saveHTML() (or saveXML()).`

may its helps you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DOMXPath` is the root of the problem because when I have this code

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    $testcontent = '<div><p>Reader&rsquo;s Digest &amp; More!</p></div>';
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($testcontent);
    echo $dom->saveHTML(); //prints the correct html
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $testcon = $xpath->query('*');
    echo $testcontent;
    foreach ($testcon->item(0)->childNodes as $child) {     
        echo "CHILD : " . $child->textContext; //prints the wrong html
        $savehtml = $dom->saveHTML($child);
    }
    echo $savehtml . '<br />';
    if ($testcontent == $savehtml) {
        echo "Match";
    } else {
        echo "No Match";
    }
?>
```

It prints `CHILD : <div><p>Reader’s Digest &amp; More!</p></div>`