# DOMDocument removing html elements

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Here is my code:

```
$text = '<div class="cgus_post"><a href="?p=15055"><div class="imgbox"><img src="/cgmedia/default.gif"></div></a>
        <h2 id="post-15055">
        <a href="?p=15055" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to Willie Nelson Celebrates 80th Birthday Stoned and Auditioning for Gandalf">Willie Nelson Celebrates 80th Birthday Stoned and Auditioning for Gandalf</a></h2>
        <p>This video pretty much sums up why Willie Nelson is fucking awesome. Willie decided to celebrate his 80th birthday by recording an ‘audition’ for Peter Jackson. &nbsp;Willie wants to take the reigns from Ian McKellan in The Hobbit 2, and decided to show off his acting skills and give some of his own wizardly advice. The result is &nbsp;hilarious. Watch …</p>
        <br class="clear">
        </div>';
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$classname = 'cgus_post';
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");
foreach($nodes as $node){
    echo $node->nodeValue;  
}
```

The problem I am having is I am querying for the div that contains the class `cgus_post` and its returning just the text. How do I have it return the HTML elements also?

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my innerHTML function that I always use:

```
function innerHTML(DOMNode $node, $trim = true, $decode = true) {
   $innerHTML = '';

   foreach ($node->childNodes as $inner_node) {
      $temp_container = new DOMDocument();
      $temp_container->appendChild($temp_container->importNode($inner_node, true));

      $innerHTML .= ($trim ? trim($temp_container->saveHTML()) : $temp_container->saveHTML());
   }

   return ($decode ? html_entity_decode($innerHTML) : $innerHTML);
}
```

So then you do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo htmlentities(innerHTML($dom->documentElement->childNodes->item(0)->firstChild));
```