# Add the `option` and `select` from an external website to my website

Tags: php, launchpad

I am trying to add the `option` tag from a ppa, as to show on my own website the current Ubuntu distro's it support.

This is what i have so far.

```
<?php include 'https://launchpad.net/~gregory-hainaut/+archive/pcsx2.official.ppa#field.series'; ?>
```

this is the content of the `option` tag:

```
<select onchange="updateSeries(this);" size="1" name="field.series" id="field.series">
<option value="YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE" selected="selected">Choose your Ubuntu version</option>
<option value="trusty">Trusty (14.04)</option>
<option value="saucy">Saucy (13.10)</option>
<option value="raring">Raring (13.04)</option>
<option value="quantal">Quantal (12.10)</option>
<option value="precise">Precise (12.04)</option>
<option value="lucid">Lucid (10.04)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you trying to include an external website's HTML code onto your own?  Or arr you trying to submit a form from your website to theirs?

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, I am trying to include an external websites HTML code onto my own!

Comment: don't try `include`... you want to try `file_get_contents` or `curl` to get the HTML and then use DOMDocument to parse it and get the section you want.

Comment: Are you doing this because the code will change overtime?  Otherwise why not just put it in yours manually?

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP,i have a website, - tutorials and such - which in I use allot of this ppa. Doing it manually, can cost a allot of time.

Comment: @BenD, i tried the following: `<?php
$ppa = file_get_contents('https://launchpad.net/~gregory-hainaut/+archive/pcsx2.official.ppa#field.series');
echo $ppa;
?>` but that just added the entire launchpad code to my website. `then use DOMDocument to parse it and get the section you want.`
.... How do i do that?

Comment: @blade19899 - I posted an answer below with details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `file_get_contents` (or `curl`) to get the actual source code, and the parse it using (for instance) `DOMDocument`. For instance, you might try something like this:

Fist define a function that lets us get the innerHTML of a node (thank you to [Hiam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)):

```
function DOMinnerHTML(DOMNode $element) 
    { 
        $innerHTML = ""; 
        $children  = $element->childNodes;

        foreach ($children as $child) 
        { 
            $innerHTML .= $element->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
        }

        return $innerHTML; 
    }
```

Then get the contents and grab the select menu by ID

```
$ppa = file_get_contents('https://launchpad.net/~gregory-hainaut/+archive/pcsx2.official.ppa#field.series');

$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($ppa);
$innerHTML = DOMinnerHTML($doc->getElementById('field.series_filter'));
```

If I echo `$innerHTML` the result is:

```
<option value="">Any series</option>
<option value="trusty">Trusty</option>
<option value="saucy">Saucy</option>
<option value="raring">Raring</option>
<option value="quantal">Quantal</option>
<option value="precise">Precise</option>
<option value="lucid">Lucid</option>
```

From that result, you'll notice I only got the *inner html* of the select menu, so you'll want to wrap the returned innerHTML in a `select` tag:

```
<select name='[your name]' [...other properties]>
<?=$innerHTML;?>
</select>
```

---

### EDITS

The OP mentioned in comments that everything is working, but he wants a different select menu than the one selected above. Because the page he is scraping **has invalid markup** (two separate `select` menus have the same `id`) the `DOMDocument` `getElementById` call is not fetching the correct node. To correct this you have to look at the DOM tree and fine a unique parent element so that you can first grab the parent node and *then* run a query to find the item you're looking for In this case, the menu that the OP wants is inside of a `div` with an ID of "", so all we do is grab that node, and then use `getElementsByTagName` to grab the select menu:

```
//... get the code (set in $ppa) as per the original section
$doc->loadHTML($ppa);

//Grab the parent div because it has a unique ID
$parent_div = $doc->getElementById('series-widget-div');
//then seach for all <select> tags and grab the first one
$select_menu = $parent_div->getElementsByTagName('select')->item(0);
//... and now we're ready to get the innerHTML
$innerHTML = DOMinnerHTML( $select_menu );
//echo it out!
echo $innerHTML;
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it gets rendered as text? when looked at with firebug, there are tags surrounding it? see: **[screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uVfoC0i.png)** same when viewing the source-code

Comment: That's because you're not wrapping the options in a `<select>` tag. I only set it to get the options, because you'll probably want to have your own `name`/`id` etc properties for the `select` wrapper. Just echo it like this: `<select name='[your name]'><?php echo $innerHTML; ?></select>`

Comment: Put [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366651/add-the-option-and-select-from-an-external-website-to-my-website/21367115?noredirect=1#comment32223379_21367115) comment in to your answer, and I will accept it. Tomorrow. Goodnight!

Comment: First off, its working great. But, i kinda wanted to keep the `(14.04)` etc. [This](http://i.imgur.com/GAHFarM.png) is how it looks now and [this](http://i.imgur.com/vFsQYtT.png) is how i am trying to get. Can't figure out how you removed the `(14.04)` etc part in the first place. The numbers are to sum more recognizable.

Comment: @blade19899 - I've updated the answer to address this. Basically, the site you're scraping has two items with the same ID (i.e. invalid markup), so you have to sort of work around the faulty DOM. I'm shown you how in the updated answer.