# DOMXpath store selected nodes to array

Tags: php, parsing, domxpath

I have this HTML:

```
$html = 
<div class="content">
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
</div>
```

and php:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$body = $xpath->query('/table');
```

This echo's out all tables:

```
echo $doc->saveXml($body->item(0));
```

1. My question is is it possible to save EACH table (with html tags) into array, so it would look like this:

   ```
   Array (
       [0] => < table> < /table> 
       [1] => < table> < /table>
       [2] => < table> < /table>
       .
       .
       .
       [n] => < table> < /table>
   )
   ```
2. Is there a short way to echo out lets say 3rd table, something like this:

   ```
   echo $doc->saveXml($body->item(3));
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [innerHTML in PHP's DomDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/innerhtml-in-phps-domdocument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to do it with *DomDocument* itself:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('Table') as $item) {
    $array[] = $item->getNodePath();
    // or do any other process if you want
}
```

To get the specific item try this:

```
$node = $doc->getElementsByTagName('Table')->item(3)
//Example:
echo $node->nodeValue
```

Comment: getNodePath() retuns ->  [0]=> string(19) "/html/body/table[1]", where can I find list of getNode..Alloptions ? is there possibility to say getNodeHtml() or something like this ?

Comment: Do you mean all child node? In the `foreach` you can say `$item->childNodes` which will give you the children of the node

Comment: If you want to convert the returned xpath to real xml string maybe this works: `SimpleXMLElement::asXML ($item->getNodePath());`