# How to filter <body> content from DOMDocument output?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

The following piece of code outputs a parsed html:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument('5.0', 'utf-8');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(($postDetails['content']), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
libxml_clear_errors();
echo $domd->saveHTML();
```

However it, outputs extra tags like `<html>`, `<head>`, etc. I want to only get the content inside the `body` tag. How do I achieve that?

For eg: if the `<body>` tag contains `<p>` or other tags that may contain content, I need to display those as it is.

Comment: @Jack The answer in that question is much cleaner. Thanks for pointing that out.

However it doesn't show a way to get rid of the body tags.

Comment: The first answer in there mentioned the body tag in the commented part of their code.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, I saw. But it doesn't apply in my case here. :/
I do have multiple nodes and it doesn't show anything to handle something like that.

Answer (score 5):

[`saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) supports an optional param `$node`. Using it you are allowed to specify a node in the Document which should be exported instead of the whole document. If you want to export the `<body>` only, then use:

```
echo $domd->saveHTML($domd->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0));
```

Comment: Just found this in an another answer. But that one doesn't have a clean way to remove the body tag

Comment: @maxxon15 Oh, I though that you want to body tag in the results. This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2087136/171318