# Scraping Links on Webpage Need to Determine if they contain Img elements

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, getelementsbytagname, getattribute

I'm building a custom scraper for a project. I can currently scrape all of the links on a webpage, storing the HREF, and anchor text in a database. However I am getting stuck when trying to determine if the anchor element contains and image element.

Here is my code:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $url = $row['url'];
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));

    // Write source page, destination URL and anchor text to the database
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        $anchor = $link->nodeValue;
        $img = $link->getElementsByTagName('img');
        $imgalt = $img->getAttribute('alt');
```

I then write the data to the database. This works fine within $img and $imgalt but I really want to identify if the anchor contains an image and also if there is an alt attribute. I know the problem is how I am trying to select the image using getElementsByTagName. I have been Googling all day and trying lots of different suggestions but nothing seems to work. Is this even possible?

I have followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087103).

There is some progress. I can echo the HTML of images within the anchor elements (if I just `echo` `DOMinnerHTML($link)`), but I still can't get the alt attribute. I keep getting "Call to a member function `getAttribute()` on a non-object".

Here is my code now:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
        $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
        $anchor = $link->nodeValue;
        $imgdom = DOMinnerHTML($link);
        $imgalt = $imgdom->getAttribute('alt');
        if(isset($imgalt)){
            echo $imgalt;
        }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If you can get image under a link so you can to determine this link contains a image as well.

Comment: Hi @felipsmartins. Apologies if I wasn't clear in my question. Bascially, I am scraping all of the links on a webpage and then storing the HREF and anchor text to a database. However I also want to check if any of the links contain image elements. It is figuring out if they have image elements that is causing me trouble.

Comment: I think @felipsmartins answer is the correct way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just can suppose you want something like this:

```
<?php

$html_fragment = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <a href="#a">there is n image here</a>
    <a href="#b"><img src="path/to/image-b" alt="b: alt content"></a>
    <a href="#c"><img src="path-to-image-c"></a>
    <a href="#d"><img src="path-to-image-d" alt="c: alt content"></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html_fragment);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    # link contains image child?
    $imgs    = $link->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $has_img = $imgs->length > 0;

    if ($has_img) {     
        $has_alt = (bool) $imgs->item(0)->getAttribute("alt");
        # img element has alt attribute?
        if ($has_alt) {
            // do something...
        }
    } else {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Remember, such as said in the PHP doc, [DOMElement::getAttribute()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domelement.getattribute.php) returns the value of the attribute, or an **empty string** if no attribute with the given name is found. So in order to check if a node attribute  exists, just check if return value is a empty string.

Comment: Thankyou for your solution. I literally just figured it out for myself 30 seconds ago! I'll mark yours as correct because it looks much cleaner than my solution :)