# Parse a HTML document and get a specific element in PHP and save its HTML

Tags: php, html

All I want to do is save the first div with attribute role="main" as a string from an external URL using PHP.

So far I have this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile("http://example.com/");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@role="main"]');
$str = "";
if ($elements->length > 0) {
    $str = $elements->item(0)->textContent;
}
echo htmlentities($str);
```

But unfortunately the $str does not seem to be displaying the HTML tags. Just the text.

Comment: Can you var_dump($elements->item(0)); without the ->textContent

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get innerHTML of DOMNode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-domnode)

Comment: `textContent` is exactly that, just the text content without HTML.

Comment: I know, but I WANT the HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the HTML via the `saveHTML()` method.

`$str = $doc->saveHTML($elements->item(0));`

Comment: That method does not exists. I think you were thinking of DOM Document

Comment: edited your anser to add the ownerDocument bit. Thanks works now!

Comment: Thanks, fixed answer.

Comment: If `ownerDocument` works, then so be it. I believe both methods should work!

Comment: Lol, my edit was slightly different: `$elements->item(0)->ownerDocument->saveHTML()`

Comment: Apologies! Please remove my answer as it's wrong. Your  ones correct though!