# how to echo a dom object such as html content

Tags: dom

this is div content i want to get from a web page.

```
<div class="result clearfix table-responsive">

    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Giải thưởng</th>
            <th>Trùng khớp</th>
            <th>Số lượng giải</th>
            <th style="text-align: left; width: 22%;">Giá trị giải (đồng)</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Jackpot</a></td>
            <td>Trùng 6 số</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td style="text-align: left"><span>27.868.784.500</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Giải nhất</a></td>
            <td>Trùng 5 số</td>
            <td>18</td>
            <td style="text-align: left"><span>10.000.000</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Giải nhì</a></td>
            <td>Trùng 4 số</td>
            <td>613</td>
            <td style="text-align: left"><span>300.000</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Giải ba</a></td>
            <td>Trùng 3 số</td>
            <td>11047</td>
            <td style="text-align: left"><span>30.000</span></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="role-result">
            <span>Thời hạn lĩnh thưởng của vé trúng thưởng: là 60 (sáu mươi) ngày, kể từ ngày xác định kết quả trúng thưởng hoặc kể từ ngày hết hạn lưu hành của vé xổ số tự chọn số điện toán (nếu có). Quá thời hạn trên, các vé trúng thưởng không còn giá trị lĩnh thưởng.</span>
    </p>

    <div>
        <a class="view-more" href="winning-numbers">Các lần quay trước</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my code to get div content and echo to my site:

```
$kqxsmega = file_get_contents ("http://vietlott.vn/vi/trung-thuong/ket-qua-trung-thuong/mega-6-45/");

$dom = new DomDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($kqxsmega);

$finder = new DomXPath($dom);

$classname="result clearfix table-responsive";

$divContent = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

My code is running good, and i want to convert $divContent become string and i can echo it.

now to echo $divContent will show nothing

```
echo $divContent ;
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you even try to read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)? The example shows EXACTLY what you're wanting to do.

Comment: i tried to use var_dump or $divContent->item(0)->nodeValue to show some text. But i want to show all such as a string included text and html

Comment: then this is a dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-domnode

Comment: may be i will use replace code or concat to get div content, will easy more