# Php Dom getting nodeValue without stripping inline element tags

Tags: php, dom

Here is the sample html:

```
$html = '<table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="background-color: #f1c40f;">Cell 1</span></td>
                        <td>Cell 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';
```

**Target is to retrieve everything between "td" tags, including the "span" tag, if any. Here is the expected result:**

```
<span style="background-color: #f1c40f;">Cell 1</span>
Cell 2
```

I tried to use DOMDocument()->getElementsByTagName("td")->saveHTML() and nodeValue without success.

Here is the php code I tried:

```
$html = '<table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span style="background-color: #f1c40f;">Cell 1</span></td>
                        <td>Cell 2</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';
            $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $html);
    $tds = $doc->getElementsByTagName("td");
    foreach($tds as $td){
        dump('saveHTML: '.$doc->saveHTML($td));
        dump('nodeValue: '.$td->nodeValue);
    }
    die();
```

Here is the outputs:

```
^ "saveHTML: <td><span style="background-color: #f1c40f;">Cell 1</span></td>"
^ "nodeValue: Cell 1"
^ "saveHTML: <td>Cell 2</td>"
^ "nodeValue: Cell 2"
```

Did I do anything wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `nodeValue` is supposed to only get you the text content, and `saveHTML` of course includes the element's own starting and opening tag. You could loop over the `childNodes` of each TD, and append the `saveHTML` result for each of them, to get the "innerHTML" of the TD.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087103/how-to-get-innerhtml-of-domnode