# How to save a neatly formatted XML file using Simple XML?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

What's the "trick" to save an XML file that visually would result neatly formatted?

such as:

```
<xml>
   <item>foo</item>
</xml>
```

and not:

```
<xml><item>foo</item></xml>
```

Comment: Possible dupe?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way

Comment: What code are currently you using to save it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the proper format of Xml is important for you instead of SimpleXml use the [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (also included and much more complex) extension that has a property for this:

```
$xml->formatOutput = true;
```

Comment: I think I'll use dom_import_simplexml before saving