# Format xml with DOM Document AND SimpleXML. Arrgghhh

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP simpleXML how to save the file in a formatted way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way)

Is it possible to use both SimpleXML and DOM Document together?

I'm using SimpleXML to get a file update it and save it but the xml is formatted on one long line.

How can I use DOM Document in the script to format the output? Does it have to be done after the SimpleXML bit hs finished writing to the file, or can it be done before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Get the wordpress postID
$postID = get_the_ID();

$postData = get_post($postID);

// echo $postID.'<br />'.$postData->post_title.'<br />'.$postData->post_date_gmt.'<br />';

$xmlFile = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/giraffetest/test.xml';

// load the document
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

// Check to see if the post id is already in the xml file - has it already been set?
$nodeExists = $xml->xpath("//post[@id=".$postID."]");

//Count the results
$countNodeExists = count($nodeExists);

if($countNodeExists > 0) { // If the ID is already in the file

        // echo 'ID already here';

        // get the correct node
        $result = $xml->xpath("//post[@id=".$postID."]/postviews");

        // heres the trick - the first result of xpath, and the node value (stored in [0])
        $result[0][0] = $result[0][0]+1;

} else { // If the ID isn;'t there, add a new entry in the xml file for the post

        //echo 'ID added';

        $postNode = $xml->addChild('post'); // adding a new <post> to the top level node
    $postNode->addAttribute('id', $postID); // adding a <postid> inside the new <post>
    $postNode->addChild('postviews', 1); // adding a postviews inside the new <post>
}

// save the updated document

//$xml->asXML($xmlFile);
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
$dom->save($xmlFile);
```

Comment: look [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Hi ahiipsa, thanks for that. Where does the code go though?

Comment: Here is my code I have written so far. Where in this file would your code need to go? - http://pastebin.com/QzRfBAeQ

Comment: update a answer (If I understand you correctly)

Comment: There is an extra ; in the loadXML line. I've removed it, but I'm getting the following error…

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMDocument::saveXML() must be an instance of DOMNode, string given, called in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/giraffetest/wp-includes/theme.php on line 1117 and defined in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/giraffetest/wp-content/themes/canvas-child/content-post.php on line 47

Comment: sorry, made a mistake, correct saveXML () -> save ()
update answer to
http://pastebin.com/vsULvGMu

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much for your help :-)

There's still the extra ; in the `loadXML` line. Should be `$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());` instead of `$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML(););`