# SimpleXMLElement will not create correct children

Tags: php, simplexml

I am using **`simpleXMLElement`** to create a new xml file.
I want to create something similar to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<command type="scenario" name="test">
    <game type="play" filename="google">
    </game>
</command>
```

I am using this code but something is not correct:

```
<?php

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><command type='scenario'></command>"); 
$xml->addAttribute('name', 'test');
$game = $xml->addChild('game');
$game->addAttribute('type', 'play');
$game->addAttribute('filename', 'google');

// checking the output
$handler = fopen(sad.xml, 'w');
fwrite($handler, $xml->asXML());
fclose($handler);

?>
```

But this is the output i see in `sad.xml` file instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<command type="scenario" name="test"><game type="play" filename="google"/></command>
```

Why?

1. New lines are not appearing in the file
2. **game** tag does not have `</game>` closing tag

Comment: is there a reason you need it to output with the spaces and a full closing tag? As far as any XML parser will be concerned, those two documents are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$game = new SimpleXMLElement('', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);    
$xml->addChild($game);
```

And you can find solutions for formatting output here [PHP simpleXML how to save the file in a formatted way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way)

Comment: I am confused, please give a the code that would output what I asked. If it works I will accept your answer. Just edit it in you answer. Thanks

Comment: Also, when I add LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG, I get number 4 in between <game></game>...???

Comment: I just read that LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG has a bug. So that is why I might get unexpected output.

Answer (score 0):

@lexicus has explained how you could achieve the output you desire. In answer to your question, "why?", there is logically no difference between your sample file and the SimpleXML output:

1. XML parsers ignore white space between tags. It doesn't matter if two tags are adjacent (`<tag1><tag2/></tag1>`) or separated by 57,392,391 empty lines; all the parsers will see are the XML elements.
2. `<game/>` is just an XML shorthand for `<game></game>`. The `/>` explicitly indicates it is an empty tag.

You are not writing a document within SimpleXML; you are building an XML tree. When you call `->asXML()` it writes out the tree in the simplest way possible.