# Formatting SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, dom, pretty-print

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/798986/1322271) it is possible to echo out formatted xml. Yet this php code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><data></data>");
$xml->addChild("child1", "value1");
$xml->addChild("child2", "value2");

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

outputs `value1 value2`

So how do I format it correctly nowadays?

Comment: :) add `<pre>` or just look page source

Comment: Where are you testing it? If from your browser, you see above output because the browser interprete the xml code. Check the page source! Your code works fine, I have tested it!

Comment: @splash58 Page source does get the result I am after. But I want it to output like that just on the page, not necessarily the colors though. `<pre>` just puts the values below each other.

Comment: @Menno Gouw https://eval.in/510254

Comment: @fusion3k Testing it on localhost. I know the code works, I'm sending the xml to an app but I want to see the xml in a browser as well (without using page source).

Comment: You want see xml code in the standard html page? If yes, try `echo htmlentities($dom->saveXML());` **Better:** `echo '<pre>'.htmlentities($dom->saveXML()).'</pre>';`

Comment: @fusion3k thanks, thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo out formatted XML (or HTML) you have to use [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) built-in function, that “convert all applicable characters to HTML entities”.

In your case:

```
echo htmlentities($dom->saveXML());
```

will output this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <data> <child1>value1</child1> <child2>value2</child2> </data>
```

Using-it together with `<pre>` html tag, also newlines and spaces will be printed:

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($dom->saveXML()) . '</pre>';
```

will output this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <child1>value1</child1>
    <child2>value2</child2>
</data>
```