# convert pipe separated text file data to xml format in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a text file generated by a device which provides me the data in this form:

```
Rajeet Singh|email@gmail.com|0123456789|Delhi  
Abhishek|email2@gmail.com|0123456987|Pune
```

I want to extract the data from the text file and convert it into XML form as shown below:

```
<user>
<item0>
<name>Rajeet</name>
<email>email@gmail.com</email>
<mobile>0123654789</mobile> 
<address>Delhi</address>
</item0>
<item1>
<name>Abhishek</name>
<email>email@gmail.com</email>
<mobile>0123654789</mobile> 
<address>Pune</address>
</item1>   
</user>
```

This is what I have done so far.

I have extracted the data from the text file and converted into an array.

```
$fh=fopen('file/dat.txt','r');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<user></user>');

while($line=fgets($fh)){
  $line_arr=explode('|',$line);
}
```

And converted a static valued array to xml like this:

```
$users_array = array(
        array(
            "name" => "Rajeet",
            "email" => "email@gmail.com",
            "mobile" => "0123654789",
            "address" => "Delhi",
        ),
        array(
            "name" => "Abhishek",
            "email" => "email@gmail.com",
            "mobile" => "0123654789",
            "address" => "Pune",
        )
);
print_r($users_array);
//function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml($array, &$xml_user_info) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            if(!is_numeric($key)){
                $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }else{
                $subnode = $xml_user_info->addChild("item$key");
                array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
            }
        }else {
            $xml_user_info->addChild("$key",htmlspecialchars("$value"));
        }
    }
}

//creating object of SimpleXMLElement
$xml_user_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><user></user>");

//function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($users_array,$xml_user_info);

//saving generated xml file
$xml_file = $xml_user_info->asXML('users.xml');

//success and error message based on xml creation
if($xml_file){
    echo 'XML file have been generated successfully.';
}else{
    echo 'XML file generation error.';
}
?>
```

But I am not sure how to format the array I got from the Text file.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? It should be feasible enough to create an XML writer and read the data via [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) using `|` as a delimiter but expecting anyone to go to all the trouble of writing all that code for you is not a reasonable expectation.

Comment: my try could not generate a fruitful result, so I thought my code might confuse others, should I edit the code and post what I did? @apokryfos

Comment: the xml you show has the email for mobile number and abishek has the same mails than rajeet. this doesnt match the code you show. please fix this.

Comment: on a side note: it's somewhat unclear what you are asking. If your question is only *"how to format the output of `SimpleXml::asXml`"*, then the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798967/php-simplexml-how-to-save-the-file-in-a-formatted-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding an [XMLWriter](http://php.net/XmlWriter) solution as an alternative.

XmlWriter can be a faster and less memory intensive solution over DOM or SimpleXml because it uses streams instead of holding the entire xml tree in memory.

Like mentioned elsewhere, you don't want `<item0>`, `<item1>` but instead use an ID attribute. [XML provides this via the xml:id attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/). The code below makes use of this.

I am using an [SplFileObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) because it is a convenient file wrapper implementing the [Iterator interface and providing CSV control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805427/how-to-extract-data-from-csv-file-in-php/2805486#2805486).

```
<?php

$reader = new SplFileObject('file/dat.txt');
$reader->setFlags(
    SplFileObject::READ_CSV |
    SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE |
    SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD |
    SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY
);
$reader->setCsvControl('|');

$writer = new XMLWriter;
$writer->openURI('file/dat.xml'); // write to this file
$writer->setIndent(true);         // format the output
$writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$writer->startElement("user");    // the root element

foreach ($reader as $row_data) {
    $row = array_map('trim', $row_data);
    $writer->startElement('item');
    $writer->writeAttributeNS('xml', 'id', null, $reader->key());
    $writer->writeElement("name", $row_data[0] ?? null);
    $writer->writeElement("email", $row_data[1] ?? null);
    $writer->writeElement("mobile", $row_data[2] ?? null);
    $writer->writeElement("address", $row_data[3] ?? null);
    $writer->endElement();
    $writer->flush();
}

$writer->fullEndElement();
$writer->endDocument();
```

Note that this requires PHP7 due to the use of the [null coalesce operator](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary) when writing the elements. If you are not on 7 yet, either update or use the old `isset`/`empty` constructs.

Comment: Not something I've used before, so I will be oft to rtfm.  Thanks!

Comment: the way is different, but the output is exactly what I was looking for. Finally, you understood my question :) Thank you @Gordon for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleXML, you can build up the hierarchy of the XML document using...

```
    $data = 'Rajeet Singh|email@gmail.com|0123456789|Delhi  
    Abhishek|email2@gmail.com|0123456987|Pune';

    $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<user />');
    $root = $xml->user;
    foreach($lines as $line){
        $data = explode("|",$line);
        $user = $xml->addChild('item');
        $user->addChild('name', $data[0]);
        $user->addChild('email', $data[1]);
        $user->addChild('mobile', $data[2]);
        $user->addChild('address', $data[3]);
    }

    echo $xml->asXML();
```

One thing which I don't do is create elements with a numeric postfix, you wouldn't normally (in XML) have elements `item0`, `item1` as this means they are different element types.  You wold simply have them all as `item`.  If you needed an index, you could create them with `item id="0"` so the id becomes the identifier (for example the unique ID of a database).

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can write as follows.

```
<?php

$string = <<<EOM
Rajeet Singh|email@gmail.com|0123456789|Delhi
Abhishek|email2@gmail.com|0123456987|Pune
EOM;

$line = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);

$tags = ['name', 'email', 'mobile', 'address'];

$xml = '';

$xml .= "<user>" . PHP_EOL;
foreach($line as $key => $row){
    $elements = explode("|",$row);
    $xml .= "<item{$key}>" . PHP_EOL;
    $boxes = array_map(NULL, $elements, $tags);
    foreach($boxes as $box){
        $xml .= "<{$box[1]}>{$box[0]}</{$box[1]}>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $xml .= "</item{$key}>" . PHP_EOL;
}
$xml .= "</user>" . PHP_EOL;

echo $xml;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to format the array from `Text file`.

```
$string = <<<EOM
Rajeet Singh|email@gmail.com|0123456789|Delhi
Abhishek|email2@gmail.com|0123456987|Pune
EOM;

$tags = ['name','email','mobile','address'];

$users_array = array_map(function($n) use($tags){
    $elements = explode('|', $n);
    return array_combine($tags, $elements);
},explode(PHP_EOL, $string));

var_dump($users_array);
```

Result...

```
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(4) {
    'name' =>
    string(12) "Rajeet Singh"
    'email' =>
    string(15) "email@gmail.com"
    'mobile' =>
    string(10) "0123456789"
    'address' =>
    string(5) "Delhi"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(4) {
    'name' =>
    string(8) "Abhishek"
    'email' =>
    string(16) "email2@gmail.com"
    'mobile' =>
    string(10) "0123456987"
    'address' =>
    string(4) "Pune"
  }
}
```